# Yii framework php: dynamically switch from TbTabs to TbDetailView

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, tabs, detailview

i don't know if the title is appropriate or that if it even makes sense. but here goes..
I'm using Yii bootstrap for my extensions and i'm really having fun with the widgets. However i have a problem.

I have 3 views that i have successfully rendered into bootstrap TbTabs..each tab contains a tbdetailview displaying some information. The purpose is to keep the user from being overwhelmed by so much information. So i could provide them with an option to display only the  information they most want to view.

However i still want to give them an option to view the whole information, all three detailviews from the tabs. By a click of a button, say "show all" or something like that. And i should be able to do that without really redirecting to another page.

I don't really necessary need to have the three detailviews merged programmatically ..just that i want to show them in the same page and hide the tabs. How should i do this?

I really have no idea on how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could place the content of the other tabs within a hidden div on the first tab. So that when on the first tab, the User can click a button that says "Show All" and then the hidden view is displayed. That's the best way I've been able to achieve similar results.